# Calculate Diagonals Elixir

Tags: elixir

i need calculate diagonals in a matrix in Elixir.
Example:

```
2p, 3, 1s
4, 2ps, 1
5s, 3, 1p

Primary   = (1 + 2 + 2)
Secondary = (1 + 2 + 5)

Result = Secondary - Primary
```

i tried N ways and i can't, please someone help me with this puzzle.
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the input? The string "2p, 3, 1s\n4, 2ps, 1\n5s, 3, 1p"? Also, can you post a few of the "N ways"
 you tried?

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect use-case for [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) comprehension:

```rb
input = [[2, 3, 1], [4, 2, 1], [5, 3, 1]]

for {row, idx} <- Enum.with_index(input),
    {col, ^idx} <- Enum.with_index(row), do: col 
#⇒ [2, 2, 1]
```

The secondary diagonal might be taken in the same way (e.g. using guard for column index, or by reversing rows. Note the use of [`Kernel.SpecialForms.^/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#%5E/1) pin operator to explicitly select diagonal elements only.

The sum of the list might be got with [`Enum.sum/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#sum/1):

```rb
Enum.sum(for {row, idx} <- Enum.with_index(input),
             {col, ^idx} <- Enum.with_index(row), do: col)
#⇒ 5
```

Answer (score 2):

With good old enumerable:

First diagonal:

```
[ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ]
|> Enum.with_index
|> Enum.map(fn({row, index}) -> Enum.at(row, index) end)

# => [1, 5, 9]
```

Second diagonal (same as above, but reverse your initial two-dimensional array):

```
[ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ]
|> Enum.reverse
|> Enum.with_index
|> Enum.map(fn({row, index}) -> Enum.at(row, index) end)

# => [7, 5, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example how to get the primary diagonal recursively, assuming the matrix is represented as nested lists. I'll leave the secondary diagonal for you to implement:

```
def primary_diag(matrix) do
  do_primary_diag(matrix, 0, [])
end

defp do_primary_diag([], index, acc) do
  Enum.reverse(acc)
end

defp do_primary_diag([row | rest], index, acc) do
  val = Enum.at(row, index)
  do_primary_diag(rest, index + 1, [val | acc])
end
```

Note that this uses `Enum.at` to fetch the value at the specified index from the row, which will be inefficient for large matrices. For 3x3 you should be fine though.